# Focusing on input should select a radio button

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

This might seem like an easy thing to do but I can't find a neat way of achieving what I want...

I have rows that contains values taken from an array in the scope. These rows also contain a radio input each and one of them contain a text input.

The original array looks something like:

```
$scope.items = [
    {name: 'one', value: 1, checked: true},
    {name: 'two', value: 2},
    {name: 'custom', value: 0, custom: true}
];
```

To make it simpler to understand I prepared a demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/rfgpz367/2/) to show how it looks.

The expected behaviour is that the first row gets selected at initialisation time. Then focusing on the text input should check the corresponding radio input.
This behaviour seems to work fine the first time you focus on the input. After that, if another radio button is checked, focusing in the input doesn't tick the matching radio button...

I tried wrapping the whole row or the input in a label linked to the radio button but it doesn't work either.

If any of you know how to handle this scenario in a neat way, I'm eager to know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you select item with `pickItem` function you change item.check property. You don't change it however when you check radio buttons with label. So this way model become desyncronized. Possible solution is to add `ng-focus="pickItem(item)"` on radio as well to fix the model in case label is used.

Here is fixed code, I also corrected HTML as little, added missing `</label>`:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="item in items">
    <input type="radio" id="radio-{{$index}}" name="foo" ng-checked="item.checked" ng-focus="pickItem(item)">

    <label for="radio-{{$index}}">
        {{item.name}}:
        <span ng-if="!item.custom">{{item.value}}</span>
    </label>

    <input type="tel" ng-if="item.custom" ng-model="item.value" ng-focus="pickItem(item)">

    <label for="radio-{{$index}}">
        <span>x 10 = {{10 * item.value}}</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/rfgpz367/3/

Comment: Thanks @dfsq ! So basically, we're reimplementing the native browser behaviour of radio buttons in JS.

I noticed your solution only works in Chrome though, not in Safari. Is that an angular bug you think?

Comment: Wrapping the input[type=tel] in a label[for] solved the issue with safari. Not pretty though...